# ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got Lparen

Tags: solidity

This is my code (I use Remix ethereum):

```
emit Transfer(_initialOwner, _initialOwner, _initialAmount);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: please show us some more lines from above that `emit ...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely using too old a compiler. You need at least version `0.4.21` for you syntax - before that version the `emit` keyword was not supported.

Also remember that just changing the first line of your code (the line where you specify the version) might not be enough as it's just a hint for the compiler - you also have to have the right version installed. If you use the latest remix.ethereum.org it should be fine, just use some of the latest compiler versions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform two things

- Change the pragma version to 0.4.21
- Change the compiler version in the remix editor [It would be in the right side of the editor, select "0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c"]

As the other user said, you need to use the higher version